# How to calculate date and time accurately in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I used this code to calculate date and time:

```
`from datetime import timedelta

date0 =  datetime.strptime('30/01/17 15:00:00', '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
date1 = datetime.strptime('31/01/17 10:30:00', '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
date2 = datetime.strptime('03/02/17 01:20:00', '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S') 

    #======Time================

delta = (date1 - date0).days
delta1 = (date2 - date0).days



TOT = (delta1 - delta)*24 
print TOT`
```

However, it is only calculate the date without time.

please help me.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm trying to understand what are you trying to achieve - if you want Time delta with days and hours, remove `.days` arg from datetime objects:

```
from datetime import datetime

date0 =  datetime.strptime('30/01/17 15:00:00', '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
date1 = datetime.strptime('31/01/17 10:30:00', '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
date2 = datetime.strptime('03/02/17 01:20:00', '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')

#======Time================

delta = date1 - date0
delta1 = date2 - date0

print delta.total_seconds() / 3600
print delta1.total_seconds() / 3600
```

Output:

```
19.5
82.3333333333
```

Comment: Well, I would like to archive a total hours. the result without time is 72. however, with time is 77. I can do it in EXCEL but in python i cannot.

Comment: Check edit, now it counts hours by division on `.total_seconds()`

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

localtime = time.localtime(time.time())
print ("Local current time :", localtime)
```

Helps to get you the current time!